# vb.net problem receiving messages using telegram bot v18

Tags: vb.net, telegram-bot

I'm trying to get messages, ID, ... out of telegram using the new telegram v18 bot.
As the bot.startreceiving has subs with arguments that are not in the startreceiving it is not going good. Tried to translate it from C# - but got errors I don't know how to solve.
Can anyone tell me what I need to change for this to get it running good?

This is what I got:

```
Imports Telegram.Bot
Imports Telegram.Bot.Exceptions
Imports Telegram.Bot.Polling
Imports Telegram.Bot.Args
Imports Telegram.Bot.Extensions.Polling
Imports Telegram.Bot.Types
Imports Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums
Imports Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups

Public Class Form1

    Public TelegramBotToken As String = "YOUR TELEGRAM TOKEN HERE"      

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Dim bot1 = New TelegramBotClient(TelegramBotToken)
        Dim receiverOptions1 = New ReceiverOptions
        bot.startreceiving(UpdateHandler, ErrorHandler, receiverOptions1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ErrorHandler(arg1 As ITelegramBotClient, arg2 As Exception, arg3 As CancellationToken)
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub UpdateHandler(bot As ITelegramBotClient, update As Update, arg3 As CancellationToken)
        If (update.Type = UpdateType.Message) Then
            If (update.Message.Type = MessageType.Text) Then
                Dim Text As String = update.Message.Text
                Dim ID1 As String = update.Message.Chat.Id
                Dim username As String = update.Message.Chat.Username
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

the
bot.startreceiving(UpdateHandler, ErrorHandler, receiverOptions1)
gives error as UpdateHandler needs args ..

If it needs to be done totally different, please let me also know

Comment: It almost certainly should be done as `AddressOf UpdateHandler` in that context; unlike in C#, VB requires the additional operator to identify when a routine should be provided as a handle and when it should be called (probably because parens are optional for a no-argument call).

Comment: Before V18 of this bot, I used: AddHandler bot1.OnUpdate, AddressOf OnUpdate
But how to do that now with this v18? as there is no onupdate in bot  ? Or I don't know where it is ....
I'm just starting again with VB.net and didn't program much in it - still bit new in it

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library, so I can't give specific advice.